# Disable TouchPad Tapping

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, mouse

I can not disable the tap to click in Lubuntu.  I have gone to Preferences --> Pointing Devices and selected the Tapping sub-menu and the box for Disable Tapping is checked.  However, I can still tap the touchpad to change the active window etc.

What is the correct way to disable this feature in lubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Mouse#Touchpad_settings is the Lubuntu Documentation on touchpad settings.  Open a terminal and enter `synclient -l`  That will give you the current touchpad settings.  Scroll down to the MaxTapTime.  It probably says MaxTapTime = 180 or some other number.  To disable tap to click according to the Lubuntu documentation enter `synclient MaxTapTime=0`.

Comment: This will disable it for the moment, but upon reboot, tapping is enabled again.